# Count Consecutive repeated values in stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics

I would like to count consecutive repeated values in stream analytics. For instance I have a sensor, which records values either 0 or 1 every second. I would like to set a sliding window of 1 minute and count if I have more than 30 consecutive 0's. I cannot count 0's in a group clause because they may not be consecutives. E.g, If I have:

```
ID Value TimeStamp
1, 1, second 1
2, 1, second 2
3, 1, second 3
4, 1, second 4
5, 1, second 5
6, 1, second 6
7, 1, second 7 
8, 0, second 8 
9, 0, second 9
10, 0, second 10
11, 0, second 11
12, 0, second 12
13, 0, second 13
14, 0, second 14
15, 1, second 15
16, 1, second 16,
17, 1, second 17
18, 1, second 18
```

I would like to obtain:

```
MinId Value Count 
1, 1, 7
8, 0, 7
15,1, 4
```

or even better, I would like to obtain that in the same minute,
there where (maximum consecutive 1's were 7 and maximum consecutive 0's where 7)

```
MinId Value MaxCount
1, 1, 7
8, 0, 7
```

In SQL I would do something like this:

```
select grp, value, min(id), max(id), count(*) as cnt, max(fecha) as Fecha
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) - row_number() over (partition by value order by id)
             ) as grp
      from [StockSensor] t
     ) t
group by grp, value
order by min(id);
```

With stream analytics you have LAG function, but I cannot find a way to count the consecutive numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: need more details:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can count number of consecutive 1s or 0s easily with the functionalities available today.
However if you would like to output all timestamps where there were x consecutive ones 1s (or 0s), you can do something like below.

```
with PreviousLookups as
(
select 
   System.Timestamp Time,
   Value,
   lag(Value,1 ) over (limit duration(mi, 1)) ValueP1,
   lag(Value,2 ) over (limit duration(mi, 1)) ValueP2,
   lag(Value,3 ) over (limit duration(mi, 1)) ValueP3,
   lag(Value,4 ) over (limit duration(mi, 1)) ValueP4
from 
    iotInput timestamp by AppTimeStamp
 )

select
   Time
from
    PreviousLookups
 where
    Value * ValueP1  * ValueP2 * ValueP3 * ValueP4 = 1
```

Above query outputs all timestamps that have 5 consecutive 1s. It can be modified for "Timestamps where there were 30 or more consecutive 0s".